# How do I structure an end-to-end test for a delegate model design?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, testing, delegates

I just ran across the Delegate-Model design (as opposed to MVC) and want to try it out, and have also been learning TDD development in a GOOS style lately.  So I'm wanting my walking skeleton test to look something like this:  (I'm using JUnit)

```
@Test
public void userGeneratesEvent_DNotifiesM_MNotifiesDOfUpdatedData_DGetsNewDataFromM() {
    Model model = new Model();
    Delegate delegate = new Delegate(model);
    model.addListener(delegate);
    // Not sure how to "generate the user event" here
    assert( ... );
}
```

My issue, as in the comment above, is that I'm not sure how to properly generate the user event from within the delegate.  Maybe my understanding of how the design pattern works is off, but the delegate should encapsulate both the view and the controller - I'd have to have the view fire an event to the contoller from within the delegate, but that interaction should be "secret"?

Any input or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your walking skeleton test should be as close to end-to-end as possible.  Your test should be from the GUI all the way to the web service or database layer if you can.  This validates everything can connect properly and you can automate deployment and run in production.

However, tests with actual web services, and databases may be too slow or fragile to automate.  In this case you test just beneath those layers using dependency injection.

For testing GUIs you can use a GUI testing framework to test through the GUI itself (this is what they did in GOOS).  If you are using Swing, I recommend [FEST](http://code.google.com/p/fest/).  Another approach that is more reliable and allows for fast acceptance tests is to test just beneath the GUI layer.  But for this, you should use MVP or MVVM instead of Delegate-Model

> I'm still stuck on how to properly go about programmatically raising a
>   user event. For example, the user adds a row into a table via the UI,
>   and I assert at the end that the number of rows in the model equals 1.
>   Do I have to break the encapsulation of the Delegate to do this?

You either have to: break encapulation, use a pattern such as MVP/MVVM that would make let you test beneath the view, or test via the GUI using FEST.  I recommend using FEST to raise events by having it automatically click on components and verify that the JTable has a given number of rows.  FEST tests are fairly reliable, albeit slow so you shouldn't write unit tests with it.

If your application grows to a decent-size (> 3000 LOC) you can consider refactoring to MVP/MVVM because you will get enough benefit from code reuse and faster/reliable end-to-end tests to justify the complexity.  Your FEST tests and unit tests (on the model) should not break during this refactoring and will help you safely refactor.  When your presenter/view-model is a separate class you can call user events on them directly and verify(with mocks)/assert that an additional table row was added.

Comment: Hmm...  This is a stand-alone app, so there's no web services.  And I'm not using a database to store data.  I'll read about FEST, which looks potentially nice for gui testing.  :)  However, I'm still stuck on how to properly go about programmatically raising a user event.  For example, the user adds a row into a table via the UI, and I assert at the end that the number of rows in the model equals 1.  Do I have to break the encapsulation of the Delegate to do this?

Comment: Ok - I will give FEST a try and respond again later.  If it works, I'll mark this as the correct answer.  :)  I'm assuming I'm actually going to have to code a base UI for FEST to actually interact with (instead of just having some basic procedural code like `raiseAddRowEvent()`) - but I'll find out.

Comment: It's looking like FEST will work great for UI testing - I'm still struggling a bit with wrapping my brain around the delegate-model paradigm.  I think I'll go back to MVC for now and get more experience with TDD and then look at delegate-model again later.  Thanks for the help.  :)